# Checking for empty Enumerable before looping

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I find myself writing the following over and over:

```
if (myEnumerable != null) {
    foreach (var element in myEnumerable) {
        DoSomething(element);
    }
}
```

It's tedious to check for NULL every time I want to enumerate, is there a better way? For instance, is there a way to override the enumerator to return "Enumerable.Empty" instead of NULL?

Comment: Better in what sense? I don't see what you are trying to improve here.

Comment: Why do you iterate over potentially null sequences so often in the first place? I almost never need to check for null before looping, because in most cases `null` is an invalid argument to my function in the first place, and validated as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, ideally design your code so that it *can't* be null. Alternatively, create an extension method:

```
 public static class EnumerableEx
 {
     public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull(this IEnumerable<T> source)
     {
         return source ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
     }
 }
```

Then:

```
foreach (var element in myEnumerable.EmptyIfNull())
    DoSomething(element);
}
```

This is much the same as Darin's approach, but moves the null coalescing operator into an extension method.

Comment: What's `T` in `T[] EmptyArray = ...`?

Comment: Of course this can significantly reduce enumeration speed if the static type of the sequence you work on is different from `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Well, to be *significant* we'd have to assume that `DoSomething` is pretty trivial. But yes, in the pretty unusual situation that you've got a compile-time type of `List<T>`, the variable can be null, you're going to do a *lot* of iterations in the normal case, and the work for each iteration is very small... in that case it could have a significant impact. Try to avoid such situations.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
foreach (var element in myEnumerable ?? Enumerable.Empty<Foo>()) {
    DoSomething(element);
}
```

but a much better way is to ensure that wherever you are fetching this `IEnumerable<T>` from never returns `null` which is the conventional way to work with enumerables in .NET.

Comment: Very good suggestion. Can we take it one step further: do you think we could override the enumerator and return "empty" instead of null?

Comment: @desautelsj, no, for me, the step further is to fix the code returning this enumerable so that it never returns null.

Comment: @desautelsj: Override *which* enumerator? You're talking about a variable which is null to start with - you just can't call anything other than extension methods on that. We have no idea what's returning the null reference to start with.

Answer (score 1):

An extension method:

```
public static EnumerableExtensions
{
  public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
  {
    return enumerable ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
  }
}
```

Then you can do

```
foreach (var element in myEnumerable.EmptyIfNull())
{
  DoSomething(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately checking for null is a fact of life...but it can be easier. I have written an extension named ValidWithItems to check for null as well as divining when not null there are items to actually enumerate.

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{

    /// <summary>Does two checks, if not null and if it has items.</summary>
    /// <returns>True if it is not null and has at least 1 item.</returns>
    public static bool ValidWithItems<T>( this IEnumerable<T> target )
    {
        return ((target != null) && (target.Any()));
    }
}
```